# Function doesn't takes Rvalue reference as parameter?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

I just made a function that takes a rvalue reference as parameter but if i pass '67', it works but let's say that "int&& ref = 67", if i pass ref as parameter it throws error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func(int&& a){
    std::cout << a << " from rvalue" << std::endl;
}


int main(){
    int&& ref = 6;
    //func(ref); // error
    func(6); // holds good
    return 0;
}

// error -> cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'int&&' to lvalue of type 'int'
```

I dont know why is it saying lvalue of type 'int' even argument is of type 'int&&'(rvalue not lvalue)
help me out what's the problem.
Thanks in Advance...............

Answer (score 3):

Within this call:

```
//func(ref); // error
```

**ref** is an **lvalue** (because it has a name) and not rvalue reference.

For make it to rvalue use **move**:

```
  func(move(ref)); // this will cast ref to rvalue
```

Dont get confused with **&&** (not everything having && in front of it is a rvalue):

```
func(int&& x) 
// && means here: you can call func() only with those expressions which can bind to rvalue (like numeric constants for ex.)
// here you allow constructing x only from rvalues
{
BUT: (here it doesnt matter any more how x got constructed)
... for every usage of x within this scope: x is lvalue (because it has a name)
```

Comment: OK. But what if i overload this function with func(int a); and invoke it as func(std::move(ref));

Comment: It's perfectly fine, because both of these are valid: int a = b; and int a = 6; For regular types (int's, floats, etc.) a = move(b) will just copy. move() gets only interesting in cases where you have types owning some resources, for ex. strings, vectors, etc.